# What does it mean if a Coordinate Reference System is deprecated?

Tags: epsg

Recently, I have discovered, that the [EPSG:4328](https://epsg.io/4328) is "deprecated". I have also found a list of EPSG codes which are deprecated [here](https://epsg.io/?q=deprecated%3A1).

EPSG:4328 has this definition:

```
GEOCCS["WGS 84 (geocentric)",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Geocentric X",OTHER],
    AXIS["Geocentric Y",OTHER],
    AXIS["Geocentric Z",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4328"]]
```

**If it has a definition, what does it mean that it is "deprecated"?**

Ie I am interested in how this is different than saying (for example) the [spherical polar coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) are deprecated. I understand what it means for a Python module to be deprecated: developers do not maintain it anymore or care about it's compatibility.

(I'm not claiming that there is anything wrong with EPSG:4328 being deprecated, I am interested in what this means in practice.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that it should not be used any more and it is likely to be removed in the next update of the database. There will be a new (better) one in the database somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

The https://epsg.org is the official source for EPSG data (not https://epsg.io). You can acquire an user account to epsg.org that is needed for browsing deprecated data. Then you can find that code 4328 is deprecated already in 2004-01-05 when it was replaced with EPSG:4978. The reason for the change:

> Name changed to omit CRS subtype and thereby reflect that in common
> usage.

In this case the new code has only different name without any functional changes.